# Event delegation from document or next static parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, event-delegation

Let's say we have the following HTML (with a button added after the page has loaded):

```
<div id="container">
    <button>Static button</button>
    <button>Dynamical button</button>
</div>
```

Now I'd like to know the exact difference between these two event handlers:

```
$(document).on('click', '#container button', function() {});

$('#container').on('click', 'button', function() {});
```

As far I as I understand the event bubbling, the second example executes the callback function slightly faster. That's because the click event gets fired when the container anchor is reached and in the first example it's fired when the document is reached.
I can imagine that in complex structured website that could cause some performance gain.

Am I right with this? Are there any other benefits? And if the performance differences are vanishing can I just attach all events to the document to guarantee that dynamically added elements are handled as well?

Comment: I'm not aware of any benefits aside from performance. If you have a small number of event handlers, or it's an event that's not going to be triggered often (i.e. not something like click or scroll), then you can generally get away with binding everything to the document.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist And what about binding all click events (let's say 50) to the document? Would that be a remarkable performance loss?

Comment: I suspect you'd need a lot more than 50 to cause problems, but I wouldn't want to commit to anything. When it comes to performance the only way to know for sure is to benchmark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are performance gains of the second version over the first.

But not because the event takes less time to bubble. That is totally negligible. Instead, it is about reduced overhead - if you bind the handler to `document`, then *all* click events in the entire document need to be tested against your selector `#container button` every time, not only those that bubbled from inside the container.

The [jQuery docs on *Event Performance*](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-performance) state this:

> Attaching many delegated event handlers near the top of the document
>   tree can degrade performance. Each time the event occurs, jQuery must
>   compare all selectors of all attached events of that type to every
>   element in the path from the event target up to the top of the
>   document. For best performance, **attach delegated events** at a document
>   location **as close as possible to the target elements**. Avoid excessive
>   use of `document` or `document.body` for delegated events on large
>   documents.